# mod-rewrite regex issue

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Why isn't this rewriting properly? Seems to me it should be working as expected

> RewriteRule ^/series/([^/]*)$ index.php?name=$1

So localhost/series/xxxx
should be redirecting to localhost/index.php?name=xxx

Comment: Remove the first slash `/series..` and try again.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA if this is in an `.htaccess`, yes -- not if this is a "real" site configuration though.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to the query string. This means you must append the `QSA` flag to your rule (Query String Append):

```
RewriteRule ^/series/([^/]*)$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA]
```

Also, as @FelipeAlamedaA mentions, if this is in an `.htaccess` you should remove the initial `/`.